# Error with growl

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a piece code as follows

```
<p:growl id="noti-growl"/>
        <h:form id="login-form">
            <p:panel>
                <h:commandButton value="Đăng nhập" class="button-login" action="index">
                    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="noti-growl"/>
                </h:commandButton>
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
```

And I recieved a error as follows

```
<f:ajax> contains an unknown id 'noti-growl' - cannot locate it in the context of the component j_idt9
```

Please explain for me? Thank for your help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reference components in JSF ajax? Cannot find component with identifier "foo" in view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either put the growl in your own form as follows

```
<h:form id="login-form">
   <p:growl id="noti-growl"/>
</h:form>
```

Or you should update with full name by putting growl in different form:

```
 <h:form id = "growlForm">    
  <p:growl id="noti-growl"/>
 </form>

 <h:form id="login-form">
        <p:panel>
            <h:commandButton value="Đăng nhập" class="button-login" action="index" update = ":growlForm:noti_growl">

        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
```